# iOS Is Testflight Autorenewable Subscription's expirationtime broken?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, testflight

I am expirencing a "bug?" while testing autorenewable subscriptions in iOS 8 with Testflight.

Apple said, that a autorenewable subscription for 1 month expires after 5 minutes in sandbox. 
For me the expiration doesn't happen after 5 min, it will renew for 12 hours.

Anyone else did notice something like that? Is it a bug or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I've the same problem with the renewal. Did you found any way to unsubscribe from the auto-renewable subscription in TestFlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, yes it is broken and it will never ever expire. Got this answer on Apple dev forums.